# How to find the size of the page numbers in a website

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I'm trying to find the size of the page numbers present in a page.

```
d.get("http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/advice/display_more.php");    
java.util.List<WebElement> list = d.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='gray2_11']/a"));
        int u=list.size();
        System.out.println(u);
```

I tried the above code , but it prints the size as "0" 
Any suggestions ?? [image: ImageAttached]

Comment: I  have added an answer for this. Please check the code and let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get back the element into visible mode.

Then call the list element. I am adding here the complete code.

```
driver.get("http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/advice/display_more.php");   


String scrollElementIntoMiddle = "var viewPortHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);"
            + "var elementTop = arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;"
            + "window.scrollBy(0, elementTop-(viewPortHeight/2));";


((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(scrollElementIntoMiddle, driver.findElement(By.className("nextBtn")));
    //((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele);
try {
     Thread.sleep(500);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}



java.util.List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='gray2_11']/a"));
int u=list.size();
System.out.println(u);
```

Comment: @sara great news . Happy to know that it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

Only to print the size of the `page numbers present` in the page you can use the following code block :

```
d.get("http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/advice/display_more.php");    
System.out.println(d.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='gray2_11']//a")).size());
```

Console Output :

```
11
```

---

### Update :

The reason you are still getting `0` elements is because you haven't upgraded your browser to latest **`Firefox Quantum`** version and latest **`GeckoDriver`** binary so try adding **`WebDriverWait`** as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver d = new FirefoxDriver();
d.get("http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/advice/display_more.php");    
System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(d, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='gray2_11']//a"))).size());
```

Comment: Looks like your and users code is same. But he is getting size = 0 on his side. Thats why i have added code to pull the element into center of screen.

Comment: but at my side it works fine with the OP s code after adding the view to center code.

Comment: @MahmudRiad Nopes, OP used `/` instead of the `//` before `<a>` tag. He should have got 1 decendent atleast. But using `//` he will get `11`

Comment: @DebanjanB I still get the OP  - 0 ??